# How to display a bullet point with this string?

Tags: jquery

How do I display this string with a bullet point?

Below is the string:

```
if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
    alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to `alert()` it, do:

```
 alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered a valid Question\n";
```

Comment: You're welcome, It's a unicode code point. See http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/

Answer (score 3):

```
alert ('\u2022 A, \n\u2022 B, \n\u2022 C, \n\u2022 D');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your strings in a resource file, strings.xml, for translation purposes. Here is how to use the bullet character in a resource file:

```
<string name="alert_validation">\n\u2022 You have not entered a valid Question\n</string>

alertValidation = getString(R.string.alert_validation);
```